# Looking for selectAll-like operation that will include calling object in the selection (whenever it matches the selector)

Tags: d3.js

The d3.js expression

```
d3.select(foo).selectAll(some_selector)
```

will return a selection comprising all the *strict* descendants of `foo` that satisfy `some_selector`.

But suppose that `foo` *itself* satisfies `some_selector`.  How can I get it included in the resulting selection when this is the case?

The following naive solution to this problem

```
d3.select(foo.parentNode).selectAll(some_selector)
```

***is incorrect***, because, in general, the selection resulting from it will include *any **siblings** of `foo` that satisfy `some_selector`*!

IOW, I'm looking for a solution that is clearer, more concise, and less of a dirty hack than this (for example):

```
// temporarily tag all candidate elements, namely, foo and all its descendants
d3.select(foo).classed('yuk', true)
  .selectAll('*').classed('yuk', true);

var parent = d3.select(foo.parentNode),
    wanted = parent.selectAll(some_selector)
                   .filter('.yuk');

// undo the tagging
parent.selectAll('.yuk').classed('yuk', false);
```

Comment: You can abbreviate wanted with: wanted = parent.selectAll('.yuk'). I don't see any problem with that. You create the same class name for the selection you want and then you select based on that.

Comment: I would omit the parent altogether making it shorter. So without the parent variable you can write: var wanted = d3.selectAll('.yuk');.

Comment: @ee2Dev: `wanted = parent.selectAll(.yuk)` would contain more than is wanted, namely those elements that do *not* satisfy `some_selector`.  Ditto for your second comment.

Comment: I would assign a class to *all* elements you want to select in a context and then use that.

Comment: What speaks against adding the .yuk class to all element satifying some_selector ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question addresses the same issue as [the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056168/how-to-generate-a-d3-selection-consisting-exactly-of-a-dom-element-and-all-its-d) you posted yesterday, although not being an exact duplicate. My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29067207/4235784) to that one will work for this problem as well. I have adjusted my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7L42ws4x/4/) to allow for some filtering on the node and its descendants:

```js
var selector = ".foo",
    x = d3.select("#x"); // your parent node

// Get all children of node x regarding selector as NodeList and convert to Array.
var xAndDescendants = Array.prototype.slice.call(  
        x.node().querySelectorAll(selector)
    );  

// Add node x to the beginning if selector is true.
if (!(x = x.filter(selector)).empty())
    xAndDescendants.unshift(x.node());

// Select resulting array via d3.js
var selection = d3.selectAll(xAndDescendants);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to avoid the class but its a bit complicated.
Here is one solution (I'm sure there are simpler ways!)..

```
 function init() {
    d3.select(foo)
        .selectAll('*')
        .call(function () {
            immediateFamily(this, function (selection) {
                return selection
                    .style('padding', '3px')
                    .style('border', '1px solid green')
            })
        })
}
;(function () {
    $(document).ready(init)
})()
function immediateFamily(selection, styling) {
    styling(selection)
    styling(d3.select(selection[0].parentNode))
}
```

The idea is to avoid repeating the styling clauses by putting them in an anonymous function in the selection chain and pass this, along with the *this* context, to a function that applies said styling to the the selection and the parent node of the first group in the selection.

To make it slightly more terse - and even less comprehensible...

```
function immediateFamily2(selection, styling) {
    styling(d3.select(styling(selection)[0].parentNode))
}
```

To take it to it's ultimate and possibly most idiomatically correct conclusion...

```
;(function () {
    $(document).ready(init2)
    function init2() {
        var foo = d3.select('tr').filter(':first-child')[0][0]

        d3.select(foo)
            .selectAll('*')
            .call(immediateFamily, bar)

        function bar(selection) {
            selection
                .style('margin', '10px 20px 10px 20px')
                .style('outline', '1px solid green')
        }
    }
    function immediateFamily(selection, styling) {
        styling(this)
        styling(d3.select(this[0].parentNode))
        return this
    }
})()
```

Of course it could be further generalised but you get the idea.

*(This code runs fine, but feel free to insert your own semicolons!)*