# How to generate a d3 selection consisting exactly of a DOM element and all its descendants?

Tags: d3.js

Suppose that `X` is some arbitrary DOM element<sup>1</sup>.  How can I generate a d3.js selection containing exactly `X` *and all its descendants*?

(Note that the selection given by `d3.select(X).selectAll('*')` will contain all the descendants of `X`, but it will not contain `X` itself.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For this question, the only constraint on `X` is that the expression `d3.select(X)` evaluate to a valid d3.js selection.</sup>

Comment: Is this the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29054620/looking-for-selectall-like-operation-that-will-include-calling-object-in-the-sel) that you asked a few hours earlier?  That question has an answer (from about an hour ago).

Answer (score 2):

Since [`d3.selectAll(nodes)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_selectAll) accepts an array-like object as a parameter you could [obtain a `NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) of all descendants of your node x, convert it to an array and add your node x to it. Passing this array to `d3.selectAll()` will return the desired selection containing node x as well as all its descendants.

Check this working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7L42ws4x/1/):

```js
var x = d3.select("#a_2").node(); // your node

// Get all children of node x as NodeList and convert to Array.
var xAndDescendants = Array.prototype.slice.call(  
        x.querySelectorAll("*")
    );  

// Add node x to the beginning
xAndDescendants.unshift(x);

// Select resulting array via d3.js
var selection = d3.selectAll(xAndDescendants);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d3.selectAll("X, X *")
```

should work